# yq e returning multiple values on a new line

Tags: newline, yq

Im running the command yq e ".property" "yamlfile.yaml" which returns all of the values with a new line -

eg.

```
- a
- b
- c
```

How do I remove the - in the yq command?

I tried using -N but it didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

added in some brackets [] and it worked aka ".property[]" "yamlfile.yaml